# C++ Cohesion with class Date

Tags: c++

I'm preparing for an exam of c++. In the last test I failed the cohesion between a class that had the Date date_event as a variable.

How to create different constructors of class P if the class P need an object Data to create an object of the class( the one with no parameters, the one with all the parameters and the copy constructor)?

Also i didn't write this Date actual class. Is it correct to write constructors like that ?

How should giorno(0) , month(0) etc work properly ?
(giorno=day, mese=month, anno= year)

```
#ifndef DATA_H
#define DATA_H
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
using namespace std;

class Data{

    friend ostream& operator<<(ostream&, const Data&);
    friend istream& operator>>(istream&, Data&);

    protected:
        int giorno;
        int mese;
        int anno;

    public:
        Data(): giorno(0), mese(0), anno(0){}
        Data(const int& g, const int& m, const int& a): giorno(g), mese(m), anno(a){}
        Data(const Data& D) : giorno(D.giorno), mese(D.mese), anno(D.anno){}
    //...
};
```

```
#include "Data.h"
class P{

protected:
          Data birthday;
public:
       P();
       P(const int, const int, const int); //i should pass day, month, year right?
       P(const P&);
}
```

Comment: I just don't get what you are trying to ask? Why are you passing the integers as references?

Comment: What is class P supposed to be? Also, you really should only use english names for variables.

Comment: Dat**e** or Dat**a**?

Comment: "how to do constructor, parameterized constructor and copy constructor" look here https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/constructors-c/

Comment: ok let's answer something. Class Is called Data due to language but in english is like Date. P class should be Person class but could be anything that needs a Data type as attribute. I'm trying to ask ( sorry for my bad english)  how to write the constructor, in specific how to use the object type Data properly beacuse if i use it in the constructor  i should inizialize it right ? (how to inizialize it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well the question is not clear, but several things can be said.

#### General

- Avoid `using namespace std;` and use the namespace directly. E.g. `friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream&, const Data&);`
- I suppose this is not the original code, but just in case : don't forget your header guards `#ifndef CLASSNAME_H`, `#define CLASSNAME_H` & `#endif /* CLASSNAME_H */`

#### Date class

- You *can* implement the constructor that way, but prefer implementing them in the `.cpp` file.
- It is unnecessary to pass the integer parameters as references. Use this for big parameters, from strings to whole objects.
- Prefer English for code, even if your colleagues/reviewers/professors are not English. It is always preferred in computer science. This is valid for variable/function names, but also for comments.

#### P(erson) class

- Give your parameters names. Often people that will use your code will only read the headers, so the headers must be as self-explanatory as possible.
- For the P contractor, try this :

```
    class Date {
        public:
            Date(const int pDay, const int pMonth, const int pYear);
            Date(const Date &pDate);

            /* Getters */
            int day(void) const;
            int month(void) const;
            int year(void) const;

            /* Setters */
            void setDay(const int pDay);
            void setMonth(const int pMonth);
            void setYear(const int pYear);

        protected:
            int mDay;
            int mMonth;
            int mYear;
    };

    class Person {
        public:
            Person(const int pDay, const int pMonth, const int pYear);
            Person(const Person &pPerson);

            /* Getters */
            Date birthday(void) const;

            /* Setters */
            void setBirthday(const int pDay, const int pMonth, const int pYear);
            void setBirthday(const Date &pDate);

        protected:
            Date mBirthday;
    };

    Date::Date(const int pDay, const int pMonth, const int pYear): 
        mDay(pDay),
        mMonth(pMonth),
        mYear(pYear)
    {
        /* Empty */
    }

    Date::Date(const Date &pDate) : 
        mDay(pDate.day()),
        mMonth(pDate.month()),
        mYear(pDate.year())
    {
        /* Empty */
    }

    int Date::day(void) const {
        return mDay;
    }
    int Date::month(void) const {
        return mMonth;
    }
    int Date::year(void) const {
        return mYear;
    }

    /* Setters */
    void Date::setDay(const int pDay) {
        mDay = pDay;
    }
    void Date::setMonth(const int pMonth) {
        mMonth = pMonth;
    }
    void Date::setYear(const int pYear) {
        mYear = pYear;
    }

    Person::Person(const int pDay, const int pMonth, const int pYear):
        mBirthday(pDay, pMonth, pYear)
    {
        /* Empty */
    }

    Person::Person(const Person &pPerson):
        mBirthday(pPerson.birthday().day(), pPerson.birthday().month(), pPerson.birthday().year())
    {
        /* Empty */
    }

    Date Person::birthday(void) const {
        return mBirthday;
    }

    void Person::setBirthday(const int pDay, const int pMonth, const int pYear) {
        mBirthday.setDay(pDay);
        mBirthday.setMonth(pMonth);
        mBirthday.setYear(pYear);
    }
    void Person::setBirthday(const Date &pDate) {
        mBirthday.setDay(pDate.day());
        mBirthday.setMonth(pDate.month());
        mBirthday.setYear(pDate.year());
    }
```

Please note that there are lots of ways to do this in a prettier fashion, and with less data copies.

Comment: The question is , how to write the implementation of the constructor  P(),P(const int, const int, const int), P(constP&)? Also yes class P was written has example without the ifndef etc , i know i need those :) , I use always english code, the class "Data" was not mine in this case.

Comment: I edited my post to give you an example of how you can implement this.